# How to change color of DataTables row?

Tags: javascript, css, datatables

I simply want to colour the rows of the table in `DataTables` according to the value of one of the cells. I have attempted two methods, as you can see (`.css` and `.addClass`) but to no avail. The `if` clause works correctly, but no colour change.

```
function colourTable(table) {
    table.rows().every(function (rowId, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
        var dir = this.data()[2];
        if (dir == 'B') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('redClass');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` is probably not what you think it is (a DOM element). See if you can `console.log(this)` to see what it actually is in this context. There is probably something like `node` or `element` off of the `this` object. So then it would be `$(this.node).css(...)`

Comment: It produces this    _Api [Array(1), context: Array(1), selector: {…}, tables: ƒ, table: ƒ, draw: ƒ, …]    but this.data()[2] works fine and gives the cells data, which to me suggests this IS the row itself?

Comment: sorry. I thought you wanted to do this in a typical html table.  in a html table, you must set background-color for it's tds, not the tr itself.

Comment: @SamPrice yes exactly, its not a DOM element so `$(this)` won't work. Usually the object will have a reference to the DOM node as part of the object. There is also this: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().nodes()

Comment: Thank you. Adding .nodes() solved the issue.